# Show page after jQuery UI has finished updating widgets

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

It is annoying that you can see the bulk buttons before $(document).ready(...
has finished buttonize them.

I have the options

1. set all classes manually in the html <- much classes which could change in next version
2. set body transparent or invisible until done

both options have disadvantages.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For what it's worth, I prefer option 1. It's not super-likely that they'll overhaul all of the class names for jQuery UI, and if they do, there can't be any more than a few dozen buttons on your site that you can update with a bulk search and replace if need be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only using html/java-script with jQuery then your options are limited to those languages. For instance if using a code behind language you could load the data for widgets before they are loaded on the client machine.

The easy method would be to hide the body.

```
 <body style="visibility:hidden">
```

then in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('Body').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Comment: Also to note you could set your widget to display:none or visibility:hidden until they are loaded. So you know display will remove the the element from the page layout while visibility will leave the space but hide the element.

Comment: <body style='display:none'>
    ...
    $(function(){
        $('body').show();    
    });

was the way i used finally